# Sending binary data to Matlab via serial

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, xbee, softwareserial, matlab

I would like to exchange data via **Xbee**. I've set up a communication based on strings between the Arduino and a Matlab software. 
Unfortunately this kind of communication isn't enough robust and sometimes messages aren't delivered correctly. So I decided to move to the **binary communication**.

**The problem:**

I'm not able to send **binary data** from the Arduino to the computer.

Let's say we want to send the decimal value 17 which is **0x11** in hex if we receive 16 from Matlab.

```cpp
[...]
SoftwareSerial xbee(pinRx, pinTx); 
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(BaudRateSerial);
  xbee.begin( BaudRateXbee );
}
[...]
void loop()
{
 while(xbee.available())
  {
    getData = xbee.read(); 
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Received: ");
    Serial.print(getData,HEX);
    Serial.println(); 
    if(getData == 16)
    {           
      // First attempt   
      //uint8_t s = 17; 
      //xbee.write(s);  -> Fail
      // Second attempt
      //xbee.write(0x11);  -> Fail
      // Third attempt
      byte message[] = {0x11, 0x11};
      xbee.write(message, sizeof(message)); 
    } 
  }
}
```

In the third attempt I tried sending an **array of bytes** and noticed that the received values were different.

```cpp
byte message[] = {0x11, 0x11};

xbee.write(message, sizeof(message));
```

The Matlab software sends data correctly. I used the [fwrite](http://www.mathworks.it/help/matlab/ref/serial.fwrite.html?searchHighlight=fwrite) function as follows `fwrite(xbee,hex2dec('10'));` and the [fread](http://www.mathworks.it/help/matlab/ref/serial.fread.html) function to receive the ack which:

> reads binary data from the device connected to the serial port object,
>   obj, and returns the data

**Matlab relevant code:**

```cpp
fwrite(xbee,hex2dec('10')); 
disp('Ack Requested...')
ack = fread(xbee);
disp(ack);
if (ack == 17) 
     % communication established
end
```

I've also tried using XC-TU to monitor traffic on Serial port (blu values are sent from the PC, red ones are received from the Arduino) and as you can see red values are different and none of them is equivalent to 17! What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: what is the range of your number?

Comment: I think the problem is in Matlab. You send data from string so `String a = "1";` is `byte 31`. Make a debug, add `Serial.println(getData,HEX);` and see what are you getting

Comment: The range is +/- 5000. I am able to receive data from Matlab. I've done the test with XC-TU to see the hex values sent from Arduino and as you can see, the boards sends every time different values. (Red ones) XC-TU and matlab receive the same data.

Comment: `xbee.write(message, sizeof(message));` this shows in MatLab as `75`,`70`??? Not sure but try to check baud rates or so. I just can't see what is wrong..

Comment: Yes exactly. Every time I click a button in MATLAB, it sends 16. Arduino receives it and responds with 17 twice. The values sent are completely different from each other. It doesn't make sense... Is the software serial library the problem?

Comment: Add `Serial.println(getData,HEX);` after `getData = xbee.read();` and say what you get

Comment: The value displayed on the serial monitor is 16

Comment: Ok, now it works. It was because of a previous sketch uploaded. There were bytes stored in the buffer. The values I was receiving belonged to an old buffer. Maybe `xbee.flush()` should do the job

Comment: if you can read "17" in the serial monitor you sent the characters "1" and then "7", not the binary number 17.

Comment: narutov6 please clear your question and problem. From now it is hard to unerstand what is wrong. Be more detail and eliminate all unnecessary parts